# Нужно перенести в каталог с изменением структуры каталога

Tags: python

Есть лежат два каталога:
 `/var/data1/` и 
 `/var/data2/`

Каталог data1 имеет структуру:

```
<version>/<name_service>/<build_number>/*_<os>_<architectura>.(zip|7z)
```

пример:

```
3.18.100/alfa/32/alfa_linux_x86_64.zip
3.18.100/zero/32/zero-ctrl_linux_i686.7z
```

Нужно перенести все файлы из `data1` в каталог `data2` с изменением структуры каталога, так что бы первым уровнем стал имя директории с названием дистрибутива и добавить разделение каталогов по архитектурам

пример:

```
alfa/3.18.100/32/linux_x86_64/alfa.zip
zero/3.18.100/32/linux_i686/zero-ctrl.7z
```

Comment: что перенести-то нужно?

Comment: файлы alfa_linux_x86_64.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получился вот такой код, немного пояснил конечно.

Один момент остался, файлы переезжают а старая структура папок остается, ее потом вручную можно дропнуть.

Закидывайте код в файл, потом, запускайте в папке на уровне с 3.18.100. Ответственности не несу. Делайте обязательно бекапы

```py
#python3.7
import os
from pathlib import Path

root_path = os.getcwd()

# Функция изменения пути
def rebuild_path(path):
    # Распаковка пути, на директории и название файла
    path, file = os.path.split(path)

    # Распаковка названия файла на имя и расширение
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)

    # Получаем список директорий
    path_list = path.split('/')

    # Собираем директории назад в другом порядке
    new_path = '%s/%s/%s' % (path_list[1], path_list[0], path_list[2])

    # Разбиваем имя файла на две части слева от _ и справа от _, правая не нужна
    new_filename, _ = filename.split('_', 1)

    # Собираем все назад
    return '%s/%s%s' % (new_path, new_filename, file_extension)


# Получаем рекурсивно список файлов, наших целей
for filename in list(Path(".").rglob("*.*")):
    # Нам нужны файлы с 3мя директориями
    if str(filename).count('/') != 3: continue
    # Получили новый путь
    new_filename_path = rebuild_path(filename)
    # Получили путь директорий файла
    mkdir_path, _ = os.path.split(new_filename_path)

    try:
        # Рекурсивное создание
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(root_path,mkdir_path))
        # Перемещение
        os.rename(str(filename), new_filename_path)
    except OSError:
        print("Creation of the directory %s failed" % mkdir_path)
    else:
        print("Successfully created the directory %s " % mkdir_path)
```

Comment: Не могу понять что не так:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./copy.py", line 19, in <module>
    new_filename_path = rebuild_path(filename)
  File "./copy.py", line 8, in rebuild_path
    path, file = os.path.split(path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 92, in split
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Comment: Python3.7 использовал,